# Only add cookie to response if it doesnt exist

Tags: java, cookies, response, session-cookies

I need to check if a cookie has already been added to the response.

I have a strange issue where my response is receiving a `Set-Cookie` header twice.

`Set-Cookie:foo=bar; Domain=dev.mysite.com; Expires=Fri, 05-May-2062 04:05:43 GMT; Path=/`

`Set-Cookie:foo=bar; Domain=dev.mysite.com; Expires=Fri, 05-May-2062 04:05:43 GMT; Path=/`

The 2 headers are exactly the same. When I debug the stack is calling this code twice. This double up of this code is due to the web stack I am using, which I can't change.

I don't care about what cookies were sent in the request, but I don't want this header sent twice.

It seems as though there isn't an easy way to find cookies added via the `addHeader` method.

During a debug, strangely if I check the headers in the response object after the `response.addCookie(myCookie);` call I don't see the `Set-Cookie` header.

Is there a way I can only add a cookie to the response if a cookie of the same name is not already being sent in the response?

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard approach. You might have to work around this issue using HttpServletResponseWrapper and remember cookies there as well?!

Comment: Yes, as mentioned by "home" - (and AFAIR) until the response is sent to the client (and received back as part of request) the cookies are not accessible to your program. The only option that you have is to "remember" which cookies you already set in your response generation.

Answer (score 0):

Home was correct.

I've created a wrapper around the `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and store the cookies in the `addCookie` method.

Then I check if the cookies exist in the list before I add another.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Set-Cookie" header if it already contains such cookie.

```
public static void addCookieIfNotExists(Cookie cookie, HttpServletResponse response) {
    boolean exists = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie").stream()
            .noneMatch(cookieValue -> cookieValue.startsWith(cookie.getName() + "="));

    if (!exists) {
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```